# How to get data attribute to controller from ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I’m having trouble passing my `$_POST` variable to my controller from an jQuery/ajax request.

Ultimately I want to be able to use that to update a field in my database.

My problem is that in trying to access `$_POST[‘quantity’]` in my controller. I keep getting the notice quantity is undefined and I’m var_dumping it and it’s null.

I’m new to jQuery/ajax and I’m not really sure how to go about fixing this issue. I could really use help in getting the data attribute, `quantity`, in my ajax request to my controller and understanding why `$_POST[‘quantity’]` is null.

I hope I am clear in my questioning and thanks for your help!

Controller function:

```
/**
 * Updates quantity using ajax/jQuery request from showCart twig file
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/quantityUpdate", name="product_quantityUpdate")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template()
 */
public function quantityUpdateAction(Request $request, $id) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $productId = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Product')->find($id);
    $cart = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:UserCart')->findOneBy(['user' => $this->getUser(), 'submitted' => false]);
    $quantity = $em->getRepository(ShopBundle:Quantity')->findOneBy(['quantity' => $productId->getId()]);

    var_dump($this->get('request')->request->get('quantity'));

    $quantity = isset($_POST['quantity']) ? var_dump($_POST['quantity']) : false;

    // $quantity->setQuantity(/* Code for finding correct product to update quantity */);
    // $em->persist($quantity);
    // $em->flush();

    return new Response ("This has been successful!");
}
```

twig / ajax & jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".spinner").spinner();
    $('input.spinner').on('spinstop', function(){
        min: 0
        console.log('spinner changed');
        var $this = $(this);
        var value = $('spinner').val();
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "{{ path('product_quantityUpdate', {'id': prodId }) }}",
            method: "POST",
            data : {
                quantity: value
            }
        }).done(function(result){
            console.log('success', result);
        }).error(function(err){
            console.log('error');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be $request->get('quantity'). Your $request is passed already. In laravel you would be able to do $request->quantity

Comment: Have you checked value of the "value" variable? Is the done() callback called? Make sure the data is sent via browser development tools (the NEtwork tab)

Comment: `request->get('quantity')` and what I have are the same thing (at least I'm pretty sure). I get the same results using your suggestion anyway

Comment: @IgorBukin it's also null...I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here

Comment: Ah found it. You don't have a class or id identifier in your js. Needs to be $('.spinner').val()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var value = $('spinner').val();
```

to

```
var value = $('.spinner').val();
```

Your selector is having problem as I see that is missing.

If you have multiple elements with same class then better use `this.value`;